# calling catch block from a method when an exception occured in try block

Tags: java

Is it any possible way there to write catch block inside a method and call it from finally when an exception occured in try block

Ex:

```
try
    {
        int a=0,b=0;
        a=b/0;      
    }
    finally
    {
        callExceptions();
    }
}
public static void callExceptions()
{
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Catch block doesn't go alone. It has to be tied with a try block.

Comment: It's not possible having catch without try! why do you need this?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to uses try/catch/finally

1.- when you want to try to use some method, if everything goes well, will continue else one exception will be thrown on catch block.

```
 try {
      // some method or logic that might throw some exception.
 } catch (ExceptionType name) {
     // catch the exception that was thrown.
 }
```

2.- It's the same the first but adding finally block means that the finally block will always be executed independently if some unexpected exception occurs.

```
 try {
      // some method or logic that might throw some exception.
 } catch (ExceptionType name) {
      // catch the exception that was thrown.
 } finally {
     // some logic after try or catch blocks.
 }
```

3.- try and finally blocks are used to ensure that a resource is closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly.  For example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
try {
    return br.readLine();
} finally {
    if (br != null) br.close();
}
```

**Referencias** [Official documentation JAVA for try/catch/finally blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

On your case:

```
public static myMethod() {    
    try {
        int a=0,b=0;
        a=b/0;      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        callException(e);
    }    
}

public static void callException(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: The above case solves my problem. But consider a scenario where the method "myMethod()" is not void and it is returning something like String. In that case, eclipse is showing an error like "This method must return a result of type String".  How to address this problem ?

Comment: yest so you need to put , **return "Something";** that you consider necessary to return it.

Answer (score 1):

`catch` block must follow a `try` block. It can't stand alone.
And `finally` block are made to be after the `catch`.

You wrote an alone `catch` inside a `finally`. That doesn't make sense.

The easiest solution is to pass the exception to the method as a parameter:

```
public static myMethod() {    
    try
    {
        int a=0,b=0;
        a=b/0;      
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        callExceptions(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // do what ever you want or remove this block
    }
}

public static void callExceptions(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for a comment so sorry it's not a direct answer to your question (as others have pointed out, that's not possible). Assuming what you're trying to do is define a common way to handle your exception logic in one place, `Callable` might be a way to go.  Something like the following might suffice...  Although I'm not going to comment on whether any of it is a good idea...

```
static E callAndHandle(final Callable<E> callable) {
    try {
        return callable.call();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return null;
    }
}

static void tryIt() {
    final String result = callAndHandle(() -> {
        // Thing which might throw an Exception
        return "ok";
    });

    // result == null => there was an error here...
}
```

Unfortunately `Runnable` doesn't declare any `Exception` in the signature, so if you know it always needs to be `void` and you don't like the `return null;` or similar hacks, you'd have to define your own interface to pass in.